# chart drawing in Java

Tags: java

I draw a chart using Java, but I don't use anything like JChart2D etc. 
I opened wolframalpha and draw a plot eg: plot[100*(x^2)] and then when you put a cursor on a plot you will see two crossing lines, which help you specify points. Can i make something like this using Java in jPanel?

Comment: Are you saying you want to draw the plot yourself?

Comment: Yes, you can. You have to be more specific, show us some code, ask about specific thing to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Yes, and with drawing a plot I don't have any problems, but I wanted to add something extra, so I thought about something like this, but is this connected with animation or threads or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do everything yourself, you'll need to add a MouseMotionListener to your JPanel that you draw into, analyze the mouse position, find the closest point on your graph to the mouse position, and update the chart to include those lines. And that over and over again, every time the mouse moves and your MouseMotionListener is called. So it can be done, but it's a lot of work.

Comment: I expect it is, but i will try. Thanks!